# How is single equals possibly in conditions?

Tags: dart

I am wondering why booleans work with either single or double equals in Dart, while the same is not true for other types like String

this works:

```
void main() {
  bool a = true;
  bool b = true;
  if (a == b) {
    print('Hello, World!');
  }
}
```

This works, too:

```
void main() {
  bool a = true;
  bool b = true;
  if (a = b) {
    print('Hello, World!');
  }
}
```

but this fails (does not compile):

```
void main() {
  String a = 'true';
  String b = 'true';
  if (a = b) {
    print('Hello, World!');
  }
}
```

But my main motivation why I've started the post is that: the same logic (single equals) does not work in my code (double is OK, and finding this took my two days). What I mean is below code compiles but condition with single equal never satisfies unless i use double equals:

```
                            if (gxcG.findWealth(model.symbol).value.isstillowned =
                                    false)
                                  {
                                    
                                    gxcG.marketOBought.forEach((element) {
                                      if (element.value.symbol ==
                                          model.symbol) {
                                        element.value.isstillowned = false;
                                      }
                                    }),
                                    if (model.portfolioname != null)
                                      {
                                        gxcForRO
                                            .find(true, model.portfolioname!)
                                            .value
                                            .marketOBought = gxcG.marketOBought,
                                      },
                                    gxcG.wealth.removeWhere((element) =>
                                        element.value.symbol == model.symbol),
                                  },
```

gxcG is a GetXController extended class, and 'findWealth' method is as below:

```
 Rx<WealthModel> findWealth(String symbol) {
    return wealth.firstWhere((element) => element.value.symbol == symbol);
  }
```

Comment: Surprisingly, there is no existing lint about this.  See https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues/3026.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing here:

```
  bool a = true;
  bool b = true;
  if (a = b){
```

Is setting `a` to `b` and then return the value assigned to `a`. Since this value is a boolean, this is "allowed" but should really not be something you are doing since it is horrible (also, you are changing `a` instead of just comparing).

You can see this change if you print `a` and `b` afterwards in an example like this:

```
void main() {
  bool a = true;
  bool b = false;

  if (a = b) {
    print('Hello, World!');
  }

  print(a); // false
  print(b); // false
}
```

The reason why this example fails:

```
void main() {
  String a = 'true';
  String b = 'true';
  if (a = b) {
    print('Hello, World!');
  }
}
```

Is because we set `a` to the value of `b` and return this value to the if-statement. But since `b` is a `String`, we cannot use this in our if-statement since it needs an expression resulting in a boolean.

Here is an (quick) example of how this syntax "can" be helpful:

```
void main() {
  String a;

  if ((a = getData()).isNotEmpty) {
    print('We got data: $a'); // We got data: Here is some data
  }
}

String getData() => 'Here is some data';
```

So since `(a = getData())` will return the value we assign to `a` (so a `String` in this case) we can use that to ask if this value is empty or not.

Comment: but why booleans are allowed to such confusing syntax but not others is one of my main concerns in the post.

Comment: The syntax is not specific for if-statements but expressions in general. It is part of the assignment syntax that the result of an assignment is the value we assign. You just ends up doing it inside an if-statement.

Comment: As long as an expression evaluates to a type which is valid within its context, it will be allowed by the compiler. The expression `a = b` is a syntactically correct expression, which evaluates to a boolean value if `a` and `b` are booleans. That's why it's allowed in that case.

Comment: @SerhatAkbak See my latest update for an example of how this syntax can be useful.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHorn. Your answer has given me what I've been looking for